# AngularJS get parameters from Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, parameter-passing

I don't know how to pass a variable from **home.blade.php** of Laravel to my **Controller.js** of AngularJS.

***LARAVEL:***

I have a home.blade.php with a variable `searchid`:

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content') 
    <div class="row" ng-app="app">
        {{ $searchid }}
        <post-controller></post-controller>
    </div>
@stop
```

This variable is send by controller of Laravel:

```
class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function makeSearch($searchid)
    {
        return View::make('pages.search')->with('searchid', $searchid);
    }   
}
```

***ANGULARJS:***

I need to pass this variable to AngularJS controller.

I have a directive file like this:

```
app.directive('postController', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
    }
});
```

And controller file like this:

```
app.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', function($scope, $routeParams)
{
      console.log($routeParams.search);
      $scope.param = $routeParams.search;
}]);
```

I don't know how to pass this variable **search** to my controller.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice package that does nearly all the work for you. [PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer)

However the basic principle is just passing variables to javascript by creating a `<script>` tag in your view and defining javascript variables. Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var searchId = {{ $searchId }};
</script>
```

**Attention** depending on the data type of your variable you'll have to use quotes around it or maybe even serialize it with json.

Comment: Put this code in my Laravel .blade.php? Between directive post-controller? And.. how i use this var in controller.js?

Comment: Yes, in your blade file. Put it right before you include the javascript files. Then in controller.js, just use it like `console.log(searchId)`

Comment: If I put in .blade.php, in console i have this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: search_test is not defined`, where "search_test" is the content of var. Any idea?

Comment: Depending on data type you have to wrap it in quotes. so do `var searchId = "{{ $searchId }}";`